# Login from other Domain using MeanJS API

Tags: angularjs, authentication, meanjs

In `MeanJS`, after a user loggedin and we refresh the page, in `core.server.controller.js` will send a user credentials to the `index.html`

```
exports.renderIndex = function (req, res) {
  res.render('modules/core/server/views/index', {
    user: req.user || null
  });
};
```

**Ques 1: Why the server knows who is the loggedin user? even we have closed the browser and reopen it.**

**Ques 2**

Lets't call the domain of above app is localhost:8000.

I have a separate website with just front-end code (`angular`) no backend.
Let's call it localhost:3000. I can call the API from localhost:8000 and display the data.

I can also login by calling localhost:8000/api/auth/signin API, but after I refresh it, it does not recognize me as signedin user because I have no server serve me the index.html like localhost:3000.

**Any trick to make localhost:8000 login works?**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding **Question 1**, that happens because of the way `express-session` is configured. If you close the browser the cookie session will persist, unless you change the options defined in `config/env/default.js`, namely:

```
// Session Cookie settings
sessionCookie: {
    // session expiration is set by default to 24 hours
    maxAge: 24 * (60 * 60 * 1000),
    // httpOnly flag makes sure the cookie is only accessed
    // through the HTTP protocol and not JS/browser
    httpOnly: true,
    // secure cookie should be turned to true to provide additional
    // layer of security so that the cookie is set only when working
    // in HTTPS mode.
    secure: false
},
```

According to `express-session` [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session) you can use `expire` and `maxAge` to control that behaviour. If both `maxAge` and `expire` are **unset** most clients will consider this a "non-persistent cookie" and will delete it on a condition like exiting a web browser application. In MEAN.js `maxAge` is set and that's why the user keeps logged in even if the browser is closed. However after 24 hours the user will need to login again.

Regarding **Question 2**, I never tried anything like that but I think the answer may be in the `domain`, `path` and `sameSite` properties of `express-session` [docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session). Take a look and see if something works out according to your needs.